# How is it possible for an eigenvector to not be in the image of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I'm trying to solve an exercise which specify the subspace $Im(T)$ (the image of a linear transformation $T$) and a vector $v$ which is an eigenvector of the [transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) (in the standard basis) but $v\notin Im(T) $.

How is that possible?

Comment: it could be an eigenvector of eigenvalue 0? does it make sense?

Comment: Yes: only eigenvectors of eigenvalue $0$ may not belong to $Im(T)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v \neq 0$ be an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $\lambda \neq 0$, then
$$v=T (v/\lambda) \in \mathrm{Im}(T)$$

so you need an example with $ \lambda =0$.

Now, if you consider any direct sum $V= W \oplus U$, the projection $T$ of $V$ over $W$ defined by
$$T(w+u)=w$$
any nonzero vector $u \in U$ is mapped to $0$ (hence it is an eigenvector), and obviously does not belong to the image of $T$.